# java.io.IOException: read past EOF Lucene in Java with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, lucene, ioexception

**What i want to do :** I have a local index created with Lucene and I need to get one value for all documents in the index.

**My problem is I can't read the index!**

My program:

```
public class index {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            read();
        } catch (CorruptIndexException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void read() throws CorruptIndexException, IOException {
        System.out.println("step");     
        IndexReader r = IndexReader.open("D:/index/DEV_IdxDOSSIER/data/index");

        System.out.println("step");
        int num = r.numDocs();
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("step3");
            Document d = r.document(i);
            System.out.println("DC_KEY: ");
            System.out.println(d.get("DC_KEY"));
        }
        /*if (!r.isDeleted(i))
        {
            Document d = r.document(i);
            System.out.println("d=" +d);
        }*/

        r.close();
        System.out.println("read doesn't work yet!");
    }
}
```

**Here is the error I got:**

```
step1
java.io.IOException: read past EOF
    at org.apache.lucene.store.BufferedIndexInput.refill(BufferedIndexInput.java:151)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.BufferedIndexInput.readBytes(BufferedIndexInput.java:116)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.BufferedIndexInput.readBytes(BufferedIndexInput.java:92)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.ChecksumIndexInput.readBytes(ChecksumIndexInput.java:43)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.IndexInput.readString(IndexInput.java:124)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfo.<init>(SegmentInfo.java:148)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.read(SegmentInfos.java:234)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryIndexReader$1.doBody(DirectoryIndexReader.java:95)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:653)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryIndexReader.open(DirectoryIndexReader.java:115)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader.open(IndexReader.java:316)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader.open(IndexReader.java:206)
    at indexation.index.read(index.java:152)
    at indexation.index.main(index.java:49)
```

PS: I'm new on Lucene. I started 1 day ago and this is for a job.

Comment: this error can be a lot of thing so don't hopeless ;)

Comment: sometimes recreates your project can be a good idea !!

Comment: hope it's gonna help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded:

```
public static void read() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Etape1");
    File indexDirectory = new File("D:/index/DEV_IdxDOSSIER/data/index");
    IndexReader r = IndexReader.open(FSDirectory.open(indexDirectory));
    System.out.println("Etape2");
    int num = r.numDocs();
    int nbrUA = 0 ;
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        Document d = r.document(i);
        System.out.println("DC_KEY: " + d.get("DC_KEY"));
        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("D:\\index\\test.txt", true);
            BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            if (d.get("DC_KEY") != null) {
                output.write(d.get("DC_KEY") + "\r\n");
                System.out.println("fichier mis à jour");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Le DC_KEY est null c'est une Unité d'Archive");
                nbrUA++;
            }
            output.flush();
            output.close();

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("the fonction write didn't Work, here is the Error");
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Erreur : pointeur null");
            System.out.println("the fonction write didn't Work, here is the Error");
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("nombre de document traité : " + (i + 1) + "\r\n");
    }
    r.close();
    System.out.println("nombre d'Unité d'Archive : " + nbrUA + "\r\n");
}
```

You must import `lucene-core-4.4.0.jar` to your library go [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java)) to read a tutorial to add lucene-core-4.4.0.

This `lucene-core-4.4.0.jar` may be different for you (only the 4.4.0 would change).

Comment: i had some problem with my librairy if you add and delete some many time you should recreat your project it can help to rewrite everything

Comment: better to use 'try and catch' for potential error than ' throws IOException'

Comment: maybe this post is not that interesting and must be deleted !

Answer (score 0):

There is a [demo](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_2_1/demo/src-html/org/apache/lucene/demo/SearchFiles.html) included in the Lucene distribution on how to search an index. You might want to take a look at that.

Comment: i already read those and many of them on internet but i still can't make my program. by the way i can't understand how Query work , but i think that is not necessary for i need.